# Use topojson to project shapefiles with different extents

Tags: gdal, topojson

I have US Census shapefiles for each decade from 1790 to 1860. Because the US grew, the extents of these shapefiles are different. Using `ogrinfo -so -al` here is the extent for 1790, `Extent: (-94.732708, 30.355644) - (-66.949831, 48.999992)`, and for 1860, `Extent: (-124.762578, 24.521051) - (-66.949831, 49.384358)`.

I want to use `topojson`'s `--projection` flag to project these to screen coordinates. Running this command works for each of the files:

```
topojson -o us_1790.json --simplify-proportion 0.10 \
  --projection 'd3.geo.albers()' \
  --width 960 \
  --height 500 \
  --margin 10 \
  -- shp/epsg4326/county_1790.shp
```

And I can then display the maps in d3. The difficulty is that each of the maps of the US is centered, which means that the map of the US in 1790 does not line up with the map for 1860, and so on. Here's what I mean:

[image: US 1790]

[image: US 1860]

I've tried using the `--bbox` flag and setting a bounding box to the extent in 1860, but that doesn't work. I've also tried searching for a way to set the extent with `ogr2ogr`.

If need be I can do the projection in the browser, but I'd prefer to pre-project them so that the map is as speedy as possible. What should I do?

Comment: The key here is that the smaller maps need to be projected to a smaller width and height than the full maps. If you assume that the full extent of the current US corresponds to your full screen width and height, you should be able to work out to what screen size the smaller parts correspond to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use `--width` and `--height`; specify the projection’s scale and translate instead, and you’ll get a fixed projection that will be the same for all inputs. In fact, since the default d3.geo.albers scale and translate is designed to fit in a 960×500 viewport, you can simply say:

```
topojson \
  -o us_1790.json \
  --simplify-proportion 0.10 \
  --projection 'd3.geo.albers()' \
  -- shp/epsg4326/county_1790.shp
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and it also let me specify the simplificataion threshold in pixels, as you write in the `topojson` docs. Thanks.